# Androidでxmlを使った点線の太さ

Tags: android, java

table_row_dotted.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_span="4"
        android:background="@drawable/dotted_line" />
</TableRow>
```

dotted_line.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="line" >
    <stroke
        android:color="@color/line_color"
        android:dashGap="2dp"
        android:dashWidth="2dp" />
</shape>
```

以上の二つのxmlを用意しました。
点線は表示されるのですが、android:layout_height="1dp"を変更したり、sizeタグに高さ設定しても線の太さ変更されません。
また、strokeタグのandroid:widthを設定すると点線自体表示されなくなってしまします。

線を太くするにはどうしたらいいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`layout_height` ＞ `stroke`タグの`android:width`じゃないとだめみたいですね。
たとえば、10dpの太さの点線を引く場合、Viewの高さは11dpとかにすれば大丈夫です。
あと、Viewに`android:layerType="software"`を指定しないと点線にならない場合があるようです。

table_row_dotted.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
～省略～
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="11dp"
        android:layout_span="4"
        android:background="@drawable/dotted_line"
        android:layerType="software" />
```

dotted_line.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="line">
    <stroke
        android:color="@color/line_color"
        android:width="10dp"
        android:dashGap="2dp"
        android:dashWidth="2dp" />
</shape>
```